# JavaEE LoginContext

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, authentication, jboss, wildfly

I am trying to do a manual login in an EJB like the Servlet Request offers.

So far so good. I implemented the CallbackHandler:

```
public class PasswordCallbackHandler implements CallbackHandler {
    private String username;
    private char[] password;

    public PasswordCallbackHandler(String username, char[] password) {
        super();
        this.username = username;
        this.password = password;
    }

    public void handle(Callback[] callbacks) throws IOException,
            UnsupportedCallbackException {
        if(callbacks == null) {
            return;
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < callbacks.length; i++) {
            if (callbacks[i] instanceof NameCallback) {
                NameCallback nc = (NameCallback) callbacks[i];
                nc.setName(username);
            } else if (callbacks[i] instanceof PasswordCallback) {
                PasswordCallback pc = (PasswordCallback) callbacks[i];
                pc.setPassword(password);
            } else {
                throw new UnsupportedCallbackException(callbacks[i],
                        "Unrecognized Callback");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My Code:

```
    PasswordCallbackHandler handler = new PasswordCallbackHandler("user", "password".toCharArray());
    LoginContext context = new LoginContext("realm", handler);
    context.login();
```

The subject shows:

```
Subject:
    Principal: user
    Principal: Roles(members:ADMIN,USER)
    Principal: CallerPrincipal(members:user)
```

So the login itself worked. My Question now is what am I doing with it? When I fetch the current principal from the container I still receive anonymous. Tested on JBoss 7.1 and Wildfly.

```
    @Resource
    private SessionContext ctx;

Principal callerPrincipal = ctx.getCallerPrincipal();
if(callerPrincipal == null) {
    return null;
}

String playerName = callerPrincipal.getName(); // Also after login() it returns anonymous.
```

So did I misunderstood this functionality? What do I need the subject for? How would I do a login where the container accepts my new user credentials?

When I use the login() from the Servlet API in a Filter it works.

greetings,
m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subject would be the key. I overlooked doAs().

Comment: Can you please elaborate on the solution?

Comment: I quote @rodrigoap,  can you elaborate a bit?